# Including multiple non defined variables

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple Discord bot that will take input from users and output it as a new nickname for another user. It works, but the new nickname needs 3 words in it. Is there a way to make it work with any number of input variables?

It first only worked with 1 word, but now I'm trying to add several words with spaces between them. And that now works too, unless the new nickname consists of more or less than 3 words. I dont really know what I'm doing, and I'm rather surprised I even got this far

```
function navnCommand(arguments, message) {
if (message.content.startsWith(".navn")){
    let args = message.content.split(" ");
    let userMention = message.mentions.users.first();
    let userNick = args[2]+' '+args[3]+' '+args[4]
    if (userMention == null){
        message.channel.send("Ey, bruk .navn @person nyttnavn din jævel")
    } else {
        let userID = userMention.id
        message.guild.members.get(userID).setNickname(userNick);
```

If the nickname lacks a variable, I get an "undefined" in the new nickname, and any more than 3 is then not included.

Comment: Don't use `arguments` as a parameter name since it's a reserved keyword. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the array-functions `slice` and `join` for that.

```js
function navnCommand(arguments, message) {
  let args = message.content.split(" ");
  let words = args.slice(2, 5); // remove the second argument to allow any number of words
  if (!words.length) {
    // Handle no words found!
  }
  let userNick = words.join(" ");
  return userNick;
}

console.log(navnCommand(null, { content: ".navn UNKNOWN Adam" }));
console.log(navnCommand(null, { content: ".navn UNKNOWN Adam Bob" }));
console.log(navnCommand(null, { content: ".navn UNKNOWN Adam Bob Charly" }));
console.log(navnCommand(null, { content: ".navn UNKNOWN Adam Bob Charly Donald" }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your arguments not the concat. result

```
   if (args.length < 3){
        message.channel.send("Ey, bruk .navn @person nyttnavn din jævel")
    } else {
        let userID = userMention.id
        message.guild.members.get(userID).setNickname(userNick);
}
```